# how to access or update variable of other component without using service class in Angular 4

Tags: angular

how to access or update other component variable without shared service

i have these two component

NOTE : these components are not Parent/Child

component 1 : **src/app/ABC/one/more/step/C1.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './C1.component.html',    
})

export class C1Component implements OnInit {


  x1:any;

  constructor() 


  ngOnInit() {    
  }

}
```

component 1 : **src/app/XYZ/two/more/step/C2.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './C2.component.html',    
})

export class C2Component implements OnInit { 


  constructor() 


  ngOnInit() {    
  }

  submit()
  {
    // after submit update the C1.component.ts variable 'x1' here
  }
}
```

Thanks ahead !

Comment: A shared service is the right way to do it.

Comment: Why do you have to do it without a shared service? That's like asking how to play baseball but saying you want to do it without a bat. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your approach, i want to know if is there a way to do that ? By the way shared service is cool way ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> You **really** should use a shared service for such a task, because you can access and modify it's properties from every component where it is injected. And it ensures angular's change detection is picking up changes properly.

---

But if you don't want to use it (please consider using it!) you could go for a static property of the component class:

```
export class C2Component {
  public static shared: string = 'foo';
}

import { C2Component } from '...';
// ...

export class C1Component {
  submit() {
    C2Component.shared = 'bar';
  }
}
```

But this will likely cause some problems regarding change detection.

*Or you could use a global variable which sits on the `window` object, but this is even worse. So please don't.*